# Calculate the argument change of the polynomial $x^{4}+10x^{3}+35x^{2}+50x+24$ and determine the number of roots by Argument principle.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, solution-verification

I want to compute the number of roots of  $$\begin{align*}
P(z) = z^{4}+10z^{3}+35z^{2}+50z+24
\end{align*}$$ on the right half plane. I know the answer should be zero since the polynomial can be factored into $$\begin{align*}
P(z) = (z+1)(z+2)(z+3)(z+4)
\end{align*}$$ and hence it does not have roots at the right half plane.

However, I want to prove this fact by using the Argument principle, but it confused me a lot.

I consider the following curve: [image]

Where the radius of the arc is $R$ and the line on the imaginary axis is from $-iR$ to $iR$. I let the arc be $\gamma_{1}$ and the straight line on the imaginary axis be $\gamma_{2}$. $P(z)$ does not have any poles or zeros on the curve.

1 ) I need to calculate the change of argument of $P(z)$ as $z$ moves one around along $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$.

For $\gamma_{1}$ $z$ clearly has argument change $\pi$ . Then for $P(z)$ , we have $$\begin{align*}
P(z) &=  z^{4} \left( 1+ \frac{10x^{3}+35x^{2}+50x+24}{z^{4}} \right)
 \\ &=  z^{4} Q(z)
\end{align*}$$ Then $$\begin{align*}
\Delta_{\gamma_{1}}\text{Arg}(P) = \Delta_{\gamma_{1}} \text{Arg}(z^{4}) +   \Delta_{\gamma_{1}}\text{Arg}(Q) 
\end{align*}$$ Since as $z \to \infty(R\to \infty)$ we have $Q \to 1$ is a number on real line, $\text{Arg}(Q) \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$ .

Then $$\begin{align*}
\Delta_{\gamma_{1}}\text{Arg}(z^{4} ) = 4 \Delta_{\gamma_{1}}\text{Arg}(z) = 4\pi  
\end{align*}$$
2 ) For $\gamma_{2}$, I consider $\text{Arg}(P(-iR)) - \text{Arg}(P(iR))$ , we have $$\begin{align*}
\text{Arg}(P(-iR)) - \text{Arg}(P(iR))  &=  \text{Arg}\left( \frac{P(-iR)}{P(iR)} \right) 
 \\ &=  \text{Arg}\left( \frac{R^{4}-35R^{2}+24+i(10R^{3}-50R)}{R^{4}-35R^{2}+24+i(-10R^{3}+50R)} \right) 
\end{align*}$$ As $R\to \infty$ , the argument goes to $\text{Arg}(1)$ which is zero.

3 )
Then the total change of argument of $P(z)$ is $4\pi$ which means there are $\frac{4\pi}{2\pi}=2$ roots on the right half plane which is clearly wrong.

What goes wrong here? Any explanation for this? Thanks.

Comment: you do not define the argument function correctly since you need to define it as a continuous function so as $\int P'/P$

Comment: @Conrad Thanks. Could you explain how should I define it here? It confuses me a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

A comment that went too long - assume we define the argument by continuity starting at $-iR$ counterclockwise, so on the curve first up and on the segment then down.

So for large $R$ since indeed then on the curve $P \sim z^4$ starting at $-iR$ on the big arc and going up, means you start at $0$ and end at $4\pi$.

However, on the vertical segment, you jump each time the imaginary part is zero and the real part is negative which corresponds to cutting the argument plane at $\pi/-\pi$ (so you do not jump  when the real part is positive since that just means going from $2k \pi+$ to $2k \pi-$ or vice versa); in particular the imaginary part is $0$ at $r^2=5, r=0$ but the real part is negative only at $r^2=5$ and then the first time you go through zero, the imaginary part goes from plus to minus since you come from up, which means you jump $-2\pi$, then at $0$ you go back with the imaginary part at $+$ but since the real part is positive, the argument doesn't jump so at $-\sqrt 5$ you jump again $-2\pi$ for a total of $-4 \pi$ canceling the jump on the arc.

Try and look at a polynomial like $z^4-5z^2+4$ which indeed has two zeroes in the right half plane and see the difference (there is no argument change on the vertical line indeed!)